# Show custom messages on dashboard menu page

Tags: dashboard

How can add custom helper message on dashboard menu page.

Say i want to add some message in "Users" menu page.

Thanks in advance to all experts bro...

Answer (score 0):

There is number of hooks dedicated for displaying admin notices in `admin-header.php`:

```
if ( is_network_admin() )
    do_action('network_admin_notices');
elseif ( is_user_admin() )
    do_action('user_admin_notices');
else
    do_action('admin_notices');

do_action('all_admin_notices');
```

Codex has [basic example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices), but admin markup is not very stable so you might need to research native notices in current version to properly replicate it.